# How to style Accelerator display text in JavaFX ContextMenu via CSS?

Tags: java, css, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

This CSS code changes the text color of the whole text of a MenuItem:

```
.context-menu .label {
    -fx-text-fill: blue;
}
```

The thing is that I only want to change the Accelerator display text.
The CSS reference of JavaFX was not very helpful: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#contextmenu

So how can you set the style of the Accelerator display text in a ContextMenu using CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I inspected the skin and found out the `accelerator-text` class is assigned to the `Label` that displays the accelerator, which means you can use

```css
.context-menu .accelerator-text {
    -fx-text-fill: blue;
}
```

to style the `Label` displaying the accelerator.

Comment: Thanks, it does work perfectly. Now I can assign the _normal_ text of a `MenuItem` a different style than the text of the `Accelerator` display text. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I just gave a menuItem an id

fxml:

```xml
<MenuItem id="menuItem" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" accelerator="Shortcut+C"/>
```

and tried:

css:

```css
#menuItem>Label {

    -fx-background-color: #0093ff;
    -fx-text-fill: #ffff00;
}
```

and it worked.

Comment: `MenuItem`s have class `menu-item`. You don't need to assign `id`s to all `MenuItem`s to style them...

Comment: Yes, it's just an example to style only one of it and not all of them.